# Delete elements from specific dimension in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an array A(x,y,z) and a list of indices j(2,4,6,..). I need to delete elements from A where elements corresponding to j should be removed from 'z' dimension like A(x,y,[z-z(j)]). Is it possible without loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Define "removed". You want to remove entire `z` slices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexing to tell which `z` slices you want out:

`A(:,:,j)=[];`